# CMake can't find SDL2_ttf?

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl, clion, sdl-ttf

So that's how my cmake looks

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(sdlsaper)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -std=c++0x -ggdb ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules)
set(SDL2_PATH "C:/Users/kamil/Downloads/SDL2-devel-2.28.5-mingw/SDL2-2.28.5/x86_64-w64-mingw32")
set(SDL2_ttf_PATH "C:/Users/kamil/Downloads/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.20.2-mingw/SDL2_ttf-2.20.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${SDL2_ttf_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES
        "src/main.cpp"
        "src/SDL_Context.cpp"
        "src/config.cpp"
        "src/utils.cpp"
        "src/texture.cpp"
        "src/text.cpp"
        "src/SDL_utils.cpp"
        "src/thumbnail.cpp"
        "src/display/display.cpp"
        "src/display/displayobject.cpp"
        "src/display/state.cpp"
        "src/display/cli.cpp"
        "src/display/cli_tags.cpp"
        "src/display/cli_command.cpp"
        "src/display/subtags.cpp"
        "src/display/info.cpp"
        "src/display/grid.cpp"
        "src/display/thumbs.cpp"
        "src/filestore/filestore.cpp"
        "src/filestore/file.cpp"
        "src/filestore/selector.cpp"
        "src/filestore/selection.cpp"
        "src/filestore/operation.cpp"
)
add_executable(sdlsaper main.cpp)


target_link_libraries(${sdlsaper} ${SDL2_LIBRARY}
        ${SDL2_ttf_LIBRARY})
```

And when i try to load my cmake i get this text:

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/kamil/AppData/Local/Programs/CLion/bin/cmake/win/x64/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find SDL2_ttf (missing: SDL2_ttf_LIBRARY SDL2_ttf_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Honestly i tried many different metods that i found on github and stack but nothing works. SDL2 alone works fine but when i try to find the ttf library something happends.

Comment: It is the script `FindSDL2.cmake` which searches SDL2 library. This script is part of your project (under `cmake_modules/` subdirectory, as you set in `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable). Usually, at the beginning of the script there is description of its usage. Read the description and find out how to hint it about location of the library.

Comment: In 2023, don't compile code with `-std=c++0x`. That locks you to an ancient version of the language.

Answer (score 0):

The package you compiled contains a `lib/cmake/SDL2_ttf/sdl2_ttf-config.cmake` which CMake's `find_package` can consume in config mode.

For that to work you need to tell CMake where to look:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${SDL2_ttf_PATH})
```

Now `find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)` will just work.

Also, both SDL2 and SDL2_ttf define nice CMake targets, so you can use modern CMake and get rid of those horrible `_LIBRARY` and `_INCLUDE_DIR` variables:

```
# This will set up both the include directories and the required link libraries
target_link_libraries(sdlsaper PUBLIC SDL2::SDL2 SDL2_ttf::SDL2_ttf)
```